Some kind of monsters kinapped a woman, inseminated her and kept in some kind of dungeon
Years ago I watched a horror movie that I barely remember, but I enjoyed it a lot. I would want to kindly ask for help in identifying it.
What I remember for 100% is that some kind of monsters kidnapped a woman, inseminated her and locked in a dungeon. I remember a scene in the dungeon where she was chained to a (made of stone?) wall. Later she gave a birth to a monster.
What those monsters are I don't really remember. I only remember that they were probably humanoid creatures.
Another scene I remember was taking place on a smart town in the middle of desert, in a Texas style of 1800s. Single street, and buildings on both sides of the street. Something like this:

The action was taking action in the modern times, I guess 90s or 2000 year. 
In the mentioned town a group of people were looking for something. Maybe for resources, maybe for something other, I don't really remember. What I remember is that they probably encountered the monsters there.
Another scene that just came to my mind is a scene where the people were hiding in some building, or a trailer. They had created an "alarm system" consisting of lines connected with metal cans that should make noise when somebody comes. However I am not sure if this scene took place 100% in this movie, I just have some flashbacks about such scene when I think about the movie.
Any suggestions would be very helpful. I am trying to find this movie since two years.
The movie was in English and is most probably an US production. The year of production is probably in range of late 90s to 2012.

This reminds me of "The hills have eyes II". The 'rape' scene you have mentioned there was in this movie too, but I don't remember that there were the other elements, I just remember that the characters of the movie were in a kind of desert, or canyon.

Yes! This is exactly this movie! Thank you very much Karen, I was looking for that movie for really long time. Now I can finally watch it again! :-)
